# ESXi 6.5 During Installation - when typing ROOT Password, Characters are repeated

Tags: vmware-esxi, keyboard

All.

I have never had this issue before.
When I get to the Root Password during the installation of ESXi 6.5.
I start typing, and it repeats the characters, and at times it will do it indefinitely, and I have to start madly hitting the backspace key or shutting off the server itself.
The keyboard is good. It is used on my main computer and swapped around to do server work here and there.
I swapped USB ports on the front of the server and rebooted the same issue.
I also used a can of computer air duster to see if that would help. Cleaned out a lot of dust and lint.
I've created multiple USB bootable ESXi 6.5's and they all show the same issue.
I tried another identical keyboard, and still the same issue.

One last note.
This is a USB keyboard, I use it for all my new server installations, and this is the first time I've ever experienced this type of keyboard-related issue.
What in the world is going on?
And how to get past it?

---**UPDATE**---
I was finally able to get past it and match my passwords.
But I had to do it very slowly for it not to mess up.
I will change the password later on when I log into the system, as the password I used was something simple to get the installation done.

So, any idea's on why the keys are multiplied?

Comment: Unbelivable. One person dislikes what I wrote, because of why? He/She does not understand the issue? Neither do I. That is why I am here asking for help.

Comment: Is this via some kind of OOB management UI like iLO/iDRAC/IMC etc. or with a a physical keboard and screen connected - I've seen major key entry issues with the OOB method, never with a physical keyboard though.

Comment: Physical screen and keyboard, and yea, this is the first time I've had it happen as well. I installed ESXi 6.5 and can work in the "Customize System" settings without an issue with the keyboard; it only happened during the installation when typing in the root password and confirmed the password.

Comment: Is the server and all it's parts up to the latest firmware revisions do you know? I've seen 'unsupported' combinations of different firmware versions on HP servers cause general odd issues, not this keyboard one however. Probably won't fix the issue, just clutching at straws - tried different keyboards? very obvious sorry

Comment: Hey, Chopper3. -- I tried a different keyboard and the same issue. All BIOS up-to-date, everything ready to install ESXi. It was a pain, but I got it installed.

Comment: Well I'm glad you're sorted but it's annoying to not know the root cause.

Answer (score 0):

I've had that happen in 6.5 and 6.7. Don't know why, but it was only on one dialog. So I opened a notepad, wrote the password and then ^C ^V (copy/paste) it into the dialog and then moved on. It never did it again after setup.

Comment: This was on the physical server, with a monitor and keyboard. So, there was no using any copy and paste techniques for this one, unfortunately.